# I called the stored procedure in my java code its returning only one row instead of 15 rows

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

Here its my code I called the stored procedure in this java file but its retrieving only one row instead of 15 rows.When I run the stored procedure separately the proper output is coming.But when I run this java file it return only one row.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.I have tried and explored but not able to fix this issue.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class DataReader {
private static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.getBoolean("debug");
private static final String srcClassName = "DataReader";
private static final String dbgDisplayOption = "both";
private static final String stringDelimiter = ",";
private static final int MAX_ROWS = 10000;
// private static final JavaUtilities jUtil = new JavaUtilities();
private static final DBUtilities dbUtil = new DBUtilities();
private static String[] symbolDataArray = new String[MAX_ROWS];
private static Connection conn = null;

private static void displayUsage() {
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Usage:");
  System.out.println("   java [-Ddebug=true] DataReader [options*]");
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("required options");
  System.out.println("   -b YYYY-MM-DD        : begin date");
  System.out.println("optionals");
  System.out.println("   -?                   : display help");
  System.exit(-1);
  }

  public static String[] retrieveRoc (
  String  beginDateString
  ) {
  final String srcCallerName = srcClassName + "retrieveRoc";

  Date   beginDate = Date.valueOf("1900-01-01");
  int    rowID = 0;

  if ( beginDateString != null)
  {
     beginDate = Date.valueOf(beginDateString);
  }

  try {
     conn = dbUtil.getDBConnection();
     if ( conn == null ) {
        System.out.println("Error: Database connection is null");
        System.exit(-1);
         }

     String commandString = null;
     commandString = "call retrieve_relstr_roc_price(?)";
     CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall(commandString);
     cstmt.setDate(1, beginDate);
     ResultSet rset = cstmt.executeQuery();
     while ( rset.next() ) {
        // System.out.println(rset.getString("close_date"));
        symbolDataArray[rowID] = rset.getString("startdate") + 
        stringDelimiter +
                                 rset.getString("enddate") + stringDelimiter +
                                 rset.getString("symbol") + stringDelimiter +
                                 rset.getString("Entryprice") + stringDelimiter +
                                 rset.getString("Exitprice")+ stringDelimiter +
                                 rset.getString("changepercentage")+ stringDelimiter +
                                 rset.getString("period_interval");
        System.out.println(rset.getString("symbol"));
        rowID++;
     }

     if ( cstmt != null ) {
        cstmt.close();
     }
     if ( conn != null ) {
        conn.close();
     }
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return (symbolDataArray);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  String beginDateString = null;
     for (int i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
     //System.out.println("coming here.." + args[i]);
     if ( args[i].equalsIgnoreCase("-b") ) {
        beginDateString = args[++i];
     } else if ( args[i].equals("-?") ) {
        displayUsage();
     }
  }

  /* validate command-line arguments */
  if ( beginDateString == null ) {
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("Error: Missing begin date");
     displayUsage();
  }

  /* display command-line arguments */

  System.out.println("Begin date       : " + beginDateString);

  retrieveRoc(beginDateString);
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a `CallableStatement`, the result is retrieved via the statement and then cast to an appropriate type (a `ResultSet` in your case)

```
cstmt.execute();
ResultSet rset = (ResultSet)cstmt.getObject(1);
```

However, this means you need an extra OUT parameter for your ResultSet, so change your sql query to something like

```
String commandString = "{ call retrieve_etf_price(?, ?)}" or even

String commandString = "{ ? = call retrieve_etf_price(?)}"
```

Now, let's assume that your OUT parameter is a ResultSet and your IN parameter is a String (I also assume an Oracle DB)

```
cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);//type for the OUT param 
cstmt.setString(2, symbol); //IN param
```

If your DB is not Oracle, you can try using java.sql.Types.OTHER but I can't guarantee that it'll work and some JDBC drivers might not even support it.

Alternatively, it's always possible to call a stored procedure using a `PreparedStatement`. (Oracle assumed but it's similar for every DB)

```
String query = "SELECT stored_proc_name(?) FROM DUAL";
PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
pStmt.setObject(1, value);

resultSet = pStmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks I will try let's see

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
  commandString = "{call retrieve_relstr_roc_price(?)}";
```

Comment: No, he still needs an OUT parameter.

Comment: You are right @dsp_user. I haven't seen that there are no outParam in the code.